# Geo-Referenced Mapping interface for ROS/RVIZ

Tags: navigation, mapping, gps, rviz, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I found this video on Youtube of a QuadCopter mapping a building on a Georeferenced Map:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_vtm46eGtU

The interface looks to be RVIZ, with the map laid across the ground plane.

Does anyone know how to import a georeferenced Map, such as a geotiff, into RVIZ to get this same effect???

I am looking for a mapping interface that can take geo-referenced maps of satellite imagery and plot the robots path and sensor information on top of it, just like the video.  I would also like to select GPS waypoints on the map, and send those to the robot to navigate too.

This needs to be done without connection to the internet.

The only other things I have found are:

**rosworldwind** - http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosworldwind: World Wind is not supported very well in Ubuntu

**ground_station** - http://www.ros.org/wiki/ground_station: Related to QuadCopters, and is no longer being updated

**gpsd_viewer**: http://www.ros.org/wiki/gpsd_viewer: Does not zoom in very good and is no longer being updated

**marble_plugin**: http://www.ros.org/wiki/marble_plugin: No high resolution Satellite images.

**Google Earth/Maps**: Google Earth/API has a lot of limitations and there licenses strictly forbids its use with autonomous vehicles. See section 10.2.C at https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

**osm_cartography**: It displays map features from Open Street Maps into rviz. OSM though does not provide satellite imagery unfortunately.

---

Looking for your guys thoughts/ideas.

Thank you

---

***UPDATE***

Some packages to maybe look into for implementation into rqt are: OSSIM (http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki) a QT geo app. Here is an example of their viewer: http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/OssimPlanet . Also some others: http://www.osgeo.org/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57313/geo-referenced-mapping-interface-for-ros/rviz/) by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe qGIS would be an option (http://www.qgis.org) too. It's not the easiest to use, but pretty powerful if you are familiar with GIS techniques and other GIS software (it uses GRASS internally to implement may of its geographic processing tools).  It's been around a while and is pretty mature and stable. It's similar in purpose to ArcGIS, and maybe OSSIM (but probably with more of a vector map emphasis than imaging); it's a general GIS toolbox  not just a viewer.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [strike_eagle_iii](https://answers.ros.org/users/38642/strike_eagle_iii/) on 2019-10-10**:
How did you use qgis?  Did you have to write your own rviz plugin?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although my answer might be just fyi since integrating with `RViz` isn't an option and this might require internet connection, I'm asking opinions and putting together requirements for [rqt](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt) plugin that plots [gps_comm](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gps_common) msgs.

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/41

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on 2013-03-06**:
rqt would also work, and would just use rqt_rviz (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt_rviz) to embed rviz into it.  I have also looked into Google Earth/API, and found that it has a lot of limitations, also there license forbids any systems or functions for automatic or autonomous control of vehicles

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just found this plugin.

https://github.com/gareth-cross/rviz_satellite

---

Originally posted by [Dani C](https://answers.ros.org/users/12031/dani-c/) with karma: 126 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/60418/l33/) on 2020-10-26**:
I just tried this plugin out in noetic, and it works!!! (demo mode), so this code is still working and maintained.